# How to include Java libraries to scala project

Tags: scala, xstream

I'm totally new to scala. I want to serialize scala objects to xml using the java xstream library. (Is this a good idea or is there a better way?)

How to install the library so that i can import:

```
import com.thoughtworks.xstream.io.{HierarchicalStreamReader, HierarchicalStreamWriter}
```

now thoughtworks is not defined.

Is there a url to add in the build.sbt?
or is there a location to copy the xstreams.jar?

Comment: Check out https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.thoughtworks.xstream/xstream/1.4.11.1 There is a "SBT" tab with the line, which you need to add to `build.sbt`

Comment: Also, googling `sbt add dependency` takes me right to https://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Library-Dependencies.html and than read `Managed Dependencies `

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To add to @GamingFelix answer about scala-xml, SBT allows to easily include Java libraries into your Scala project.

When adding `libraryDependencies` to your project, you would usually write something like this:

```
libraryDependencies ++= "com.somecompany" %% "someproject" % "1.0.0"
```

This will attempt to resolve the following Maven project:

```
com.somecompany:someproject_2.12:1.0.0
```

**Note the `_2.12`!**

To import a Java project, you have to instead write:

```
libraryDependencies ++= "com.somecompany" % "someproject" % "1.0.0"
```

**Note the single `%` instead of the double `%%`!**

Now, SBT will try to resolve the Maven project:

```
com.somecompany:someproject:1.0.0
```

Which is the one you are looking for.

So, in your case write:

```
libraryDependencies += "com.thoughtworks.xstream" % "xstream" % "1.4.11.1"
```

When searching on Maven, you will actually be given such import statements right away:

https://search.maven.org/artifact/com.thoughtworks.xstream/xstream/1.4.11.1/jar

Answer (score 4):

There is actually very good support for xml in the standard scala library.
I think you can read more about it here:
`https://github.com/scala/scala-xml`
All you need to do is to add the import in your class

```
import scala.xml
```

If you really want to use the java library instead. You can probably import it by adding the dependency into your `build.sbt`.

*(Edit to include this part of the answer by ygor)*

Check out `mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.thoughtworks.xstream/xstream/…` There is a "SBT" tab with the line, which you need to add to `build.sbt`.

Comment: since Scala 2.11.0, scala-xml isn't part of the Scala standard library anymore, it's a separate dependency